# Expected identifier or "(" error on .h file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, include

I have inherited development of an iPhone app that was originally created overseas.  The original developers are no longer available for questions.  The app is currently available on the app store.  So I assume the zip file that I received of the project is current and complete.

When I first open the project in xcode and do a build, I get hundreds of errors.  They are all the same basic error.  There are hundreds of .h files with one line:

```
../../../FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/Internal/ServerConfiguration/FBSDKServerConfiguration.h
```

I get the error "expected identifier or '(' on the first character of this line in every file.

I tried changing the line to:

```
#include "/../../../xxxxxxxxx"
```

and that worked.  But as I said, there are several hundred of these files in the project.  If this was a running app 'supposedly' from this source code, why should I need to go change hundreds of files and add #include to each line?

This project uses an old version of swift, and I had to go all the way back to xCode 7 to find a development environment that would support it.  Is the .h syntax in these files some sort of deprecated syntax that stems from an even older version of xCode?  Can some seasoned iPhone app developer tell me about this particular .h file syntax of including another .h file (and why it's failing for me now)?

Basically, if I need to change all of the .h files, then so be it.  But I'm more than a bit concerned making this drastic a change to code that supposedly recently built a running app.

Suggestion?  Enlightenments?  Thanks.

Jerry

Comment: Where exactly are those files located and how are they named? Are you sure that they should be part of the project and must be compiled?

Answer (score 0):

The "syntax" you described -- just a single line containing a file name (with a relative path)

```
../../../FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/Internal/ServerConfiguration/FBSDKServerConfiguration.h
```

has never ever been correct C/C++/Objective C (preprocessor) syntax. Either is some strange, proprietary custom preprocessing is running, or it's just garbage.

Using

```
#include "/../.."
```

is also nonsense: If you start a path with `/`, you start at the root directory, so navigating up with `..` will lead you to root again, and `xxxxxxxxx` is expected exactly there in the root directory.

This was to the syntax. The semantics is hard to tell without the project.

- Maybe it might just help if you completely remove those strange header files,
- or comment out the erronous lines
- or you need to adjust your include paths in the project to help Xcode find the files

Comment: Andreas, that was a typo in my 'fix'.  I meant to say #include "../../../xxxxxx"  (just putting #include and quotes around what was there.  Not starting at root).

Comment: Martin, I'm just learning the project.  So I don't really understand the 'why' of the structures yet.  But in every case there is the included h file and then the same name under a 'private' file path and another under a 'public' file path.  All three have the same .h file name... the actual .h and the private/public path that apparently include the main.  No clue yet as to the private/public stuff.  Been programming for years.  But this is my first iOS app.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: Andreas, thank you so much for your assessment.  In all my years as a programmer of many languages, the syntax I found made zero sense.  But I just didn't want to rule out some new 'shortcut' syntax that 'everyone' knows about now.   I'm going to write a script to blast the #include syntax into all of these files and move on.  But I guess I'll always have the nagging question.... how did it EVER work with this syntax.  Oh, well, no time to pursue that mystery now.  The fun of inheriting a project with no documentation... :-(   Thanks again, Andreas & Martin